# how to use jquery and greasemonkey to select an option at google analytics?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-analytics, greasemonkey

Not a total noob when it comes to JS, but started yesterday with JQuery... :)

I want to make GA show 50 lines at a time by default - using GM + JQuery!
(not in the internal settings).

Plus, i dont want to make any request by myself - GA must do it.
I just want to choose the number "50" in the Select/ComboBox/DropDown and trigger the default action.
(a POST, if im not mistaken).

what i got so far:

```
$(".ACTION-toggleRowShow option[value=50]").attr("selected",true).click();
```

it works 50%.
all pages start with "50" selected, but the extra lines are not shown.
maybe its not triggering anything?

already tried

with `$('.ACTION-toggleRowShow').val('50').change();`
and `$('.ACTION-toggleRowShow').val('50').trigger();`
and `$('.ACTION-toggleRowShow').get(0).selectedIndex = 2;`
and `$('.ACTION-toggleRowShow').val('50').trigger('change');`
and `$('.ACTION-toggleRowShow').val('50').trigger('click');`

none of them worked for me.
(they all choosed the correct value '50', but not even one was able to trigger the event).

[image: GA - field marked in red]

thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, this should do what you want:
Select option with the value 50 and trigger the change event

```
$('.ACTION-toggleRowShow').val('50').trigger('change');
```

Comment: already tried `$('.ACTION-toggleRowShow').val('50').trigger('change');`    and    `$('.ACTION-toggleRowShow').val('50').trigger('click');`  - none of them work